# MacOS not storing proxy settings in keychain

Tags: macos, proxy, keychain, http-proxy

I am having issues with the UI prompt which is asking me to enter my password to access the keychain credentials for proxy.

My mac is used in a local network without internet access, so I need to setup a proxy connection with username and password for browsing and all other mac services. I configured proxy including authentication in network settings. When browsing, chrome asks me once to enter credentials and it is working fine after then. If any other system service tries to connect, I am getting prompted to enter my password so proxy credentials can be fetched from keychain. I also changed the keychain entry to allow all applications to access it, but the prompt keeps on asking and asking and asking for my password. The next time, the keychain entry is changed back again to allow only some applications. Looks like it is always overriding the old entry.

Any ideas how I can fix that? Unfortunately I do not have any access on configuration of the proxy server or to change any parameters there, if it is a configuration issue of the proxy server. But there has to be a solution, I do not think entering the password hundreds of times a day can be an accepted solution.

My Mac is newly setup and running macOS Big Sur 11.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106742/mac-username-password-for-proxy-settings-keep-resetting-by-itself? Usually you can move the password item in the keychain to the System section rather than the login section and this fixes the issue.

I have a similar issue but I am in a corporate environment and my issue seems to be related to NTLM https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/292835/how-to-store-proxy-credentials-on-macos-so-they-are-used-by-system-services?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it was not working for me. My issue might also be related to you mentioned NTLM issue. I managed to change my network configuration, to only use proxy on dedicated IPs, so I was able to reduce requests to the proxy, which helped me do reduce the amount of prompts significantly, so for me this workaround "solved" it. I still get issues when using whole communication via proxy, but I do not do this anymore in most cases.